# Need libc APIs to access disk geometry and partitioning related info

Tags: c, linux, api, hard-drive

I am working on a new project, which relates to creating drive images for backup.

As a part of it, i need to write code which can give much useful information related to disk geometry - cylinders, no. of sectors, partitions, and file systems and even drive specific info, like which partition is present on which drive. i need some APIs.

If you can post a code too in addition to APIs that will be great.

**P.S: Something similar to what Novell - Zenworks (Imaging) does**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no glibc facility for that. Use [libblkid](http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/libblkid-docs/).

Comment: `liblkid` is only for ext2 file types, what if there is also an `NTFS` partition? Or `DEL partition`? `liblkid` can't detect that.

Comment: It is part of e2fsprogs, but it supports [many more filesystems](http://git.kernel.org/?p=fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git;a=blob;f=lib/blkid/probe.h).