# get physical hdd's list in c

Tags: c, linux, hard-drive

People, I need get the list of hard disk connected in C language on Linux system:

Example, running a program on a computer with 2 IDE disks and 1 SATA disk connected.

```
./a.out
```

Out required:

```
/dev/hda
/dev/hdb
/dev/sda
```

help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need libc APIs to access disk geometry and partitioning related info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478519/need-libc-apis-to-access-disk-geometry-and-partitioning-related-info)

Answer (score 1):

Use [libsysfs](http://linux-diag.sourceforge.net/Sysfsutils.html), the recommended way to query the kernel about attached devices of all kinds.

Comment: I will check it out.. but I found 'ls /sys/block/' and I think it is a good solution. I need the more standart way. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE *fp = popen("fdisk -l | grep \"Disk /\" | awk '{print $2};' | sed 's/://'", "r");
while(fgets(path, sizeof(path) -1,fp) != NULL)
//your code
pclose(fp);
```

Comment: This requires root on my system

Comment: @natinusala, Use `sudo` before `fdisk` if user is present in `sudoers list`.

Comment: It was just to point this out, if you want the code to be portable you shouldn't rely on code needing a root permission

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be simply read and parse `/proc/partitions`.

Comment: This is the way what I don't want to do :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reference fdisk's source code.
Follow this website:
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/fdisk

Answer (score 0):

**Command Line**
  "ls /sys/block/"

**will return output as:**

> sda sdb sdc

*From there, you could creat a script that pipes it to a file, then read in that file as an array or linked list to manipulate the data however you see fit (such as adding /dev/ in front of all device names in the list).*